# Reference for derived functor

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I'm following a course in algebraic geometry and in 2-3 month we will see the cohomology of schemes using derived functors.

I don't know anything about it, (and about category theory in general), and I want to be prepared a bit. What is the best thing I can read ? I'm interested in particular by references which are not too long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can recommend Hilton-Stammbach's *A course in homological algebra*

Comment: Thanks ! I will take a look. My first idea was to take Rotman's book but derived functors appears around 400 pages after the beginning...